# Incorrect results of Mean and Variance of TransformedDistribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics

I am solving a problem from 17th Kolmogorov competition.
Let $(x,y)$ be a Gaussian random vector with mean $(0,0)$ and a covariance matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&r\\r&1\end{array} \right),$$ where $|r|\le 1$. Find   mean and variance of  $\max(x,y)$. My try in 13.2 on Windows 10 is as follows.

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `(2 Sqrt[1 - r] + Sqrt[2] r - Sqrt[2] r^2 +  Sqrt[2] (-1 + r) Abs[r])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])`

```
Variance[TransformedDistribution[ Max[x, y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `Piecewise[{{(-1 + Pi + r)/Pi, Inequality[0, LessEqual, r, Less, 1]}},  (-1 + Pi + r + 2*r^2 - 4*r^3 + 2*r^4)/Pi]`

If $r=-1$, then $\max(x,y)=|x|$ and the above results are not in accordance with

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[RealAbs[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]
```

> `Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]`

and

```
Variance[TransformedDistribution[RealAbs[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]]
```

> `(-2 + \[Pi])/\[Pi]`

I think it should be `r` instead of `Abs[r]` in the result for the mean.

How to obtain the correct results with Mathematica?

PS.Rewriting $\max(x,y)$ in other formulas does not help:

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[(RealAbs[x - y] + RealAbs[x + y])/2, 
{x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `(Sqrt[1 - r] - Sqrt[2] r^2 + Sqrt[1 + r] +  Sqrt[2] r Abs[r])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]`

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[ RealAbs[x - y]/2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]] + 
Mean[TransformedDistribution[RealAbs[x + y]/2, {x, y} \[Distributed]BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[\[Pi]] + Sqrt[1 + r]/Sqrt[\[Pi]]`

Comment: For `Abs[r]==1` the covariance matrix `{{1, r}, {r, 1}}` is not invertible. How is the Gaussian defined then?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Thank you for your interest to the question. Sorry for the delay in my reply: force majeure. First, the case `r==-1` should be considered as the limit when `r` tends to `- 1` from above. BTW, OK with `r==1`. Second, there are problems with other negative values of `r`. For example, `(2 Sqrt[1 - r] + Sqrt[2] r - Sqrt[2] r^2 + Sqrt[2] (-1 + r) Abs[r])/(  2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) /. r -> -0.5` produces `0.0925749`, whereas `Mean[TransformedDistribution[   Max[x, y], {x, y} \[Distributed]     BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, -0.5]]]` results in `0.690988`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without adding `Assumptions` (on Windows 10, *Mathematica* 13.2.0.0) I get the same "wrong" mean (at least wrong for $-1 \leq r < 0$). From @BobHanlon 's answer, the answer depends on the operating system.  However, on Windows 10, *Mathematica* 13.2.0.0 one can get the right formulas for the mean and variance for $-1<r<0$ by adding in that assumption in `TransformedDistribution`:

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y], 
  {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r], 
  Assumptions -> -1 < r < 0]]
(* Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[π] *)

Variance[TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y], 
  {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r], 
  Assumptions -> -1 < r < 0]]
(* (-1 + π + r)/π *)
```

The rest of this is just an extended comment providing support (rather than "verification") that for the formula for the mean, `Abs[r]` should be `r` and the desired function for the variance.

When one doesn't have an exact formula or is unsure of a formula, simulations can be helpful.  Below a million samples are taken for several values of `r` and the sample mean determined.  That is plotted against the two formulas for the mean.

```
t = Table[{r, Mean[Max[#] & /@ RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r], 1000000]]},
  {r, -0.99, 0.99, 0.02}];

Show[Plot[{(2*Sqrt[1 - r] - Sqrt[2]*r^2 + Sqrt[2]*r*Abs[r])/(2*Sqrt[Pi]), 
  Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[Pi]}, {\[Rho], -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.8}}, PlotStyle -> {{LightGray, Thickness[0.015]}, {Cyan, Thickness[0.015]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, LightGray, Cyan}, {"Simulations", 
  "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2\\\ \*SqrtBox[\(1 - r\)] - \*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\\\ \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)] + \*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\\\ r\\\ Abs[r]\), \
\(2\\\ \*SqrtBox[\(\[Pi]\)]\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2\\\ \*SqrtBox[\(1 - r\)] - \*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\
\\\ \*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)] + \*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\\\ \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\), \(2\\\ \*SqrtBox[\(\[Pi]\)]\)]\)=\!\
\(\*FractionBox[SqrtBox[\(1 - r\)], SqrtBox[\(\[Pi]\)]]\)"}]],
 ListPlot[t, PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]]
```

[image: Simulations and two formulas for the mean]

For the variance the formula *Mathematica* produces is also wrong for $-1\leq r <0$:

```
v = Table[{r, Variance[Max[#] & /@ RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r], 1000000]]},
   {r, -0.99, 0.99, 0.02}];

Show[Plot[{Piecewise[{{(-1 + Pi + r)/Pi, Inequality[0, LessEqual, r, Less, 1]}}, 
  (-1 + Pi + r + 2*r^2 - 4*r^3 + 2*r^4)/Pi], (-1 + Pi + r)/Pi}, {r, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1.8}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.015], LightGray}, {Thickness[0.015], Cyan}},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, LightGray, Cyan}, 
  {"Simulations", "Piecewise function", "(-1+Pi+r)/Pi"}]], 
 ListPlot[v, PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]]
```

[image: Variance from simulations and 2 formulas]

Comment: Thank you for your work and +1. Indeed, the true answers are `Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[π]` and `(-1 + π + r)/π`. The ones may be derived by  making use of the identity `Max[x,t]===RealAbs[x - y] + RealAbs[x + y])/2`.

Comment: @user64494 Just added in the use of `Assumptions` but that doesn't fix the somewhat pathological case of $r=-1$ as `TransformedDistribution` complains if one sets `r` to -1.

Comment: In my comment  I have had in mind the proof by hand.

Comment: JimB (@ does not work): It is not a good practice to substantially edit a post without any indication of changes. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user64494 "substantial" is in the eye of the beholder.  I placed adequate text about the edits in the "Edit summary" (which I think were better than some that I've seen before such as "added 586 characters in body").

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = BinormalDistribution[r];

DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* -1 < r < 1 *)

dist2 = TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y], {x, y} \[Distributed] dist];

μ = Mean[dist2]

(* Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[π] *)

Limit[μ, r -> #] & /@ {-1, 1}

(* {Sqrt[2/π], 0} *)

var = Variance[dist2]

(* (-1 + π + r)/π *)

Limit[var, r -> #] & /@ {-1, 1}

(* {(-2 + π)/π, 1} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work and +1. This is basically that I do, but  on Mac. On Windows 10 I still obtain `(2 Sqrt[1 - r] - Sqrt[2] r^2 + Sqrt[2] r Abs[r])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])` for the mean.

Comment: @user64494, I can confirm that `"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"` , `"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"` and `13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2022)` (Wolfram Cloud) all return the mean with `Abs[r]`.

Comment: @Domen: Thank you.

Comment: On an older laptop with `13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)` I get an incorrect result initially, but repeated evaluations are somewhat quicker and get to the correct result. I would **guess** that the initial evaluation is timing out before it comes to the correct result and an unverified intermediate result is returned. However, subsequent calculations have access to cached intermediate results and get to the correct solution in time.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I can confirm your guess on "13.2.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)". After the 3rd evaluation of the Mean, I get the same result as you did.

Comment: Having executed `Mean[TransformedDistribution[
  Max[x, y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
   BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]` 6 times in 13.2 on Windows 10, I obtained `(2 Sqrt[1 - r] - Sqrt[2] r^2 + Sqrt[2] r Abs[r])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])` every time.

Comment: @user64494 Here also after 6th time Mean[Tra... gets to small result. After you get correct result it never fails again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround in 13.2 on Windows 10. Making use of the identity (In my PS this was written incorrectly.) $$ \max(x,y)= \frac {|x-y|+x+y} 2$$ and the property of mean $E(u+v)=E(u)+E(v)$ which is valid for all random variables $u,v$ (of course, s.t. at least two of these means exist), one obtains

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[(RealAbs[x - y])/2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[\[Pi]]`

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[(x + y)/2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `0`

In order to find the variance of $\max(x,y)$, one should use the independence of $x+y$ and $x-y$ which follows from

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[(x - y)*(x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `0`

and

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[x + y, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `0`

and

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[x - y, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]
```

> `0`

I leave the rest on your own.

Comment: The rest is `Variance[
 TransformedDistribution[(x + y)/2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
   BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]+Mean[TransformedDistribution[((x - y)/2)^2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
   BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, r]]]-(Sqrt[1 - r]/Sqrt[\[Pi]])^2`.

Comment: Do you think it is a bug ultimately?

Answer (score -1):

We are given  $(X,Y) \sim$ standard Bivariate Normal, with correlation coefficient $r$ and pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

Then $E[\text{max}(X,Y)]$ is given immediately as:

[image]

and $\text{Var}[\text{max}(X,Y)]$ is:

[image]

where I am using the `Expect` and `Var` functions from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. The salient point is that it should not be necessary to first find the transformed distribution, and to then find the moments of the latter: we can find the moments of the transformed variable directly wrt to the parent standard bivariate Normal pdf.

Comment: Can you kindly give a link to  the mathStatica package? I don't find it at this forum. In other case this is empty talk.

Comment: There are more than 60 articles on this forum on mathStatica. Just do a search.

Comment: Sorry, I repeat I don't find a link to download  mathStatica at this forum as well as  a link with its description.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Is there a link to download Mathematica on this forum? If you can provide that, many people might find that helpful.

Comment: Can you give any link with the description of mathStatica and  any link to download the one? In other case this is empty talk.

Comment: @user64494 : this responder consistently uses this site as covert advertising for his non-free product. Downvote as an unresponsive "answer".

Comment: @user64494 Re your request for a link describing the software used to answer these questions. The description link for Mathematica can be found at http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica and the description link for mathStatica can be found at http://www.mathstatica.com.  You can get a free trial of Mathematica at https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/   There were free early versions of mathStatica available with the Springer book "Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica" . You can download a completely free PDF copy of that Springer book at http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html